# Фиксированное количество знаков после запятой в Python

Tags: python

Есть ли в python аналог функции `toFixed()` в JS? Мне нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
>>> a = 12.3456789
>>> a.toFixed(2)
'12.35'
>>> a.toFixed(0)
'12'
>>> b = 12.000001
>>> b.toFixed(3)
'12.000'
```

Comment: Различные варианты Вам уже написали в ответах. Я решил еще добавить про [precision](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/okruglenie.html
Может не совсем то, но в моем случае, я искал именно это

Comment: есть же numpy. 
numpy.round(число, числа после запятой)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Аналог [`Number.prototype.toFixed()` из JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) в Python 3.6+:

```
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"
```

Пример:

```
>>> numObj = 12345.6789
>>> toFixed(numObj)
'12346'
>>> toFixed(numObj, 1)
'12345.7'
>>> toFixed(numObj, 6)
'12345.678900'
>>> toFixed(1.23e+20, 2)
'123000000000000000000.00'
>>> toFixed(1.23e-10, 2)
'0.00'
>>> toFixed(2.34, 1)
'2.3'
>>> toFixed(2.35, 1)
'2.4'
>>> toFixed(-2.34, 1)
'-2.3'
```

Comment: А что за литерал f? И как подцепились переменные в строке? Видел подобное в JS, но там строка специального вида

Comment: @gil9red PEP 498

Comment: Офигеть, спасибо :) Полезно читать https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html :)

Comment: 3.6 круто, но старые платформы типа 2k3 он не поддерживает

Comment: @vadimvaduxa: на старых версиях: `"{numObj:.{digits}f}".format(**vars())`

Answer (score 11):

Прямого аналога нет. Можно попробовать

```
a = float('{:.3f}'.format(x))
```

Пример:

```
>>> x = 3.1234567
>>> x = float('{:.3f}'.format(x))
>>> x
3.123
```

Comment: Можно еще так: `format(3.1234567, '.3f')`

Comment: @gil9red век  живи, век учись)) Спс, не знал.

Answer (score 5):

Вот так можно указать количество знаков после запятой при выводе:

```
a = [1000, 2.4, 2.23456754323456, 2754.344]
for i in a:
    print('%.3f' % i)  # 3 знака после запятой
```

Вывод:

```
1000.000
2.400
2.235
2754.344
```

[Здесь](http://pythoner.name/formatted-output) подробнее.

Comment: а чем запись print('%.3f' % i)  лучше(хуже) записи x = float('{:.3f}'.format(x)) ?

Comment: @Rashid-s, рекомендуется в Python 3 использовать format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382719/python-way-of-printing-with-format-or-percent-form

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется что вы слегка усложняете. Есть чудесная функция round(), в которую в можете передать число, а через запятую передать количество знаков после. Так как всё равно там будет округление

```
d = round(3.14, 1)
print(d) # 3.1
```

Comment: Вы пробовали тестировать ваше решение на примерах из вопроса?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что ТС что-то услажняет? `round (123.000001, 3) # 123.0`, но ожидаемый результат другой. Он является нескромным желанием? Если да, то почему?

Answer (score 1):

```
def toFixed(f: float, n=0):
    a, b = str(f).split('.')
    return '{}.{}{}'.format(a, b[:n], '0'*(n-len(b)))

f = 7.123
print(toFixed(f, 10))  # 7.1230000000
print(toFixed(f, 2))  # 7.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Я для этого использую встроенный модуль. Понятно, что он возвращает Decimal, но я потом обратно преобразую во float.

```
from decimal import Decimal
number = Decimal('0.424242')
number = number.quantize(Decimal('1.000'))
number = float(number)
# возвращает true, т.к. оба типа данных теперь float
print( 0.424 == number )
```

Answer (score 0):

если нужно не округлить, а именно обрезать знаки после запятой
n = float(input())

print(int(n * 1000) / 1000)

или

n = float(input())

print(n * 1000 //1 /1000)

или

a=input()
print(float(a[:5])) #если заранее известно количество знаков

или

import math

print(math.floor(float(input()) * 1000)/1000.0)