# Python - Количество знаков после запятой

Tags: python-3.x

Есть результат X = 0.25, но так же результат может быть X = 0.3333.... 
Задача: Вывести 6 знаков после точки. Например если Х = 0.25, нужно вывести 0.250000, а для X = 0.33333333333, вывести X = 0.333333

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Фиксированное количество знаков после запятой в Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/648454/%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
X = 0.33333333333
print("{:6f}".format(X))
0.333333

X = 0.25
print("{:6f}".format(X))
0.250000
```