# python формат дробного числа?

Tags: python

немного странное поведение Python

```
a = 119.6
b = a-0.01

print(a,b)
```

Получаю: 119.6 119.58999999999999
А хочу получить 119.6 119.59
Почему так происходить как исправить?

Comment: Есть вопросы
Которые были актуальны всегда
И которые будут актуальны всегда)

Answer (score 2):

Это довольно известная проблема и заключается она в неточности вещественных чисел. Дело в том, что в памяти все числа хранятся в двоичном формате и для некоторых десятичных чисел с малым количеством знаков после запятой порой требуется огромное количество знаков после запятой в двоичной системе. А так как память не бесконечна и получаются такие мелкие неточности.

**Решение** данной проблемы заключается в том, что бы ограничить количество выводимых знаков после запятой (взято из https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/648659/428851)

```py
def toFixed(numObj, digits=0):
    return f"{numObj:.{digits}f}"
a = 119.6
b = a-0.01
print(a, toFixed(b, 2))
```